Is it possible to read a "Manual of Gainful Exercise" while you fight?
Basically, I wish to read the Manual faster, but I'm locked in either work or combat almost every waking hour. Is it possible to continue to read my Manual WHILE fighting or working? I would greatly prefer not staying up for 6 days in a row to finish the Manual, as by then I could be dead from exhaustion.

No, you have to study the manual and practice the exercises
First, the 2024 DMG is not out yet, so we currently must use the rules from the 2014 DMG, and this answer may change when the new version comes out.
The rules text for the Manual of Gainful Exercise says:

This book describes fitness exercises, and its words are charged with magic. If you spend 48 hours over a period of 6 days or fewer studying the book's contents and practicing its guidelines, your Strength score increases by 2, as does your maximum for that score.

When you are fighting or working, you are not studying the book and practicing its guidelines. You are fighting or working. If you cannot take time out to study the book and practice, you will not make progress. And since you need to spend 48 hours within at most 6 days, you need to be able to spend, on average, 8 hours per day.
That is the same amount of hours you travel in a day of overland travel (p. 20, PHB) or that you can spend on a day crafting items (p. 233, PHB), so it is pretty clear that you need to be mostly preoccupied studying and practicing during those days.

Alright, thanks for the help with this. I just wanted to find a way to not lose 6 days of sleep to read the Manual, since usually I don't have long to do things. I've already had to fight god twice in the span of like, one week, and also participated in the Tournament of Power, fought Jiren, and some other stuff.

@Tasi - I feel like you are trying to play out the Dragon Ball Z show within Dungeons and Dragons rules. But the latter is not suited to the former.

@Tasi Well, you might not be putting into practice your Manual of Gainful Exercise anyway as not sleeping (i.e. having a long rest) for consecutive multiple days is a really bad idea anyway as you will die from Exhaustion if you fail the constitution saving throws. O_o

@Obie2.0 it's more so whatever the DM thinks would be interesting. I fought Sonic.EXE without spells twice now, mostly it's just what would be most fun.

It sounds very free-form, so why even ask rule-based questions? Clearly, whatever your group agrees goes in this sort of game, so you can make whatever rules you think are most interesting.

@Obie2.0 It's more like, my character mostly follows D&D rules aside from the fusing, and the others just do their own thing. D&D character with D&D mechanics in a mostly non-D&D environment
